# Best way to build icons?

Tags: android, drawable

There's some question I wanted to ask, in developing Android Applications what do you prefer to do when it comes to Icons and Images in `Drawable` which is gonna use in your application as default content.

it's more like a standard question so it doesn't require technical mindset.

Do you think it's better to use 4 or 5 different size image as android suggest and let Android itself decide which size is appropriate to use depends on the device screen size (in the drawable folder with 4 or 5 folder called "**hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi etc**") or using only one large size asset to optimize the size of your apk.

Comment: take a large image, and try to import that image in AndroidStudio using ImageAsset. It will automatically create you all the necessary sub images and folders,

Comment: It's not an answer @MohdAsifAhmed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `svg drawables` from [flat icons](https://www.flaticon.com/) than make xml for this using [svg2android](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) tool. create xml in your drawable folder paste code from `svg2android`. and use it as a drawable.

This approach is much efficient than using different drawables for different screen sizes.  this does not require scaling for different screen sizes.